# How to ask correctly for Android problems

Tags: discussion, android

I have seen so many Questions in `SO` and I really wanted to help these guys, but I was not able because something was missing or I could not really figure out what their problem was. So today I read the 1000th `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and `NullPointerException` question here and I decided to start this Thread.

**How do I ask a android question in StackOverflow correctly:**

Comment: I don't want to be "that guy" but this question should be in meta.stackoverflow :P

Comment: Speaking of thread exceptions `throw new ThreadOnStackOverflowException()`

Comment: @pablochan So you think I should remove this, sorry do not get it

Comment: Not sure, this information is useful, but (ironically) the question itself does not fit the profile of this site.

Comment: I have nothing against `NullPointerException` questions as long as they are being asked in a resonable way; with good formating, nice explenation, and at least with basic understanding of the problem.

Comment: I don't think questions for NetworkOnMainThreadExceptions are a problem. I've seen way more questions where I just have facepalm.

Comment: As others have said, it should be on meta and it is of itself unfortunately useless.  Since we don't have stickies, and you are targeting people who by and large do not attempt to help themselves first, how will they find this thread when after the first hour, it's already buried on page 3?

Comment: You are really right guys, but I really want to help the Android people to fix their problems and I will use this thread to help them to ask it the right way. If you think I should move it just close this thread and I will delete it.

Comment: The intention is good and it's excellent that someone does something to improve the sad state of the Android tag. The way I see this kind of post should be done is as a community wiki "android tag FAQ" post on meta. We can then help both novices and ourselves by linking to the FAQ on meta.

Comment: This question got closed as dup so cannot post an answer. FYI, I went ahead and edited the tag wiki http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info - adding a mention about logcat on top and links to some frequently asked questions such as NetworkOnMainThreadException. The FAQ list can be expanded with "canonical" questions that are often the target of duplicate flagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for reading this. Everybody of us startetd programming, but you have to research and research and read and read to get better and better. 
Just asking for a solution is not the best approach. 
Try to understand the problem and try to solve it on your own.

If you can not get rid of a crash/exception just ask us, but **we need some information to help you**.

1. Post some code and try to explain what you want to do and what exactely is the problem.
2. **If you get an exception or the app crashes:** Post your `LogCat` to the question, read the `LogCat` and check for your `package` name and post the line concerned to the `exception`.
   And then google the `exception`.

For Example:

```
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at com.example.evilmonster.lobby.LobbyScene.createScene(LobbyScene.java:52)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at com.example.evilmonster.base.BaseScene.<init>(BaseScene.java:41)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at com.example.evilmonster.lobby.LobbyScene.<init>(LobbyScene.java:31)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at com.example.evilmonster.managaer.SceneManager$2.onTimePassed(SceneManager.java:150)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.handler.timer.TimerHandler.onUpdate(TimerHandler.java:94)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.handler.UpdateHandlerList.onUpdate(UpdateHandlerList.java:47)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdateUpdateHandlers(Engine.java:618)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onUpdate(Engine.java:605)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine.onUpdate(LimitedFPSEngine.java:57)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine.onTickUpdate(Engine.java:568)
12-20 14:12:05.556: E/AndroidRuntime(18957):    at org.andengine.engine.Engine$UpdateThread.run(Engine.java:858)
```

`com.example.evilmonster.lobby.LobbyScene.createScene` is my package and the Line is 52.
**My code is like:**

```
private MonsterBody myBody; 
    @Override
    public void createScene() {
        myBody.getBody();       
    }
```

How to get the `LogCat` is described inside this article:  http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidLogging/article.html

3. Please do also some research on your own for the given `exception`. 
   We have about 3 billion hits on `google` for `NetworkOnMainThreadException` and you will find a solution for it on your own.
4. Keep in mind we do not provide a ready to deploy solution, but everybody of us is really trying to help you.

Thank you for reading!  ;)

**P.S. please edit this post if you think I forgot something or I did something wrong.**

Answer (score 2):

Just adding two small points to A.S. answer:

- When you program doesn't do what you want, but **doesn't crash**

Explain what **works**

Example:

> "I want to display an image in the top left corner but it doesn't work."

--> Does the image appear or not? If it doesn't, what to you see? If it does, where is it compared to what you expect?

I really often see some posts where there is a really nice description of what should be achieved, and some code posted, but no explanation about what the code currently does.
This make it more difficult to help. In this example, knowing that the image is displayed but not at the right place is a helpful information

- When people give you an answer or a hint that doesn't work

Try to use that hint to find some more solution or information.

Example, in your question's comment, someone wrote:

> "According to your log, you have a NullPointerExeption at line 150"

--> Don't come back instantly on Stack Overflow saying "here is line 150, what should I do?". Try to solve it from the hint first

Answer (score 1):

i think `NetworkOnMainThreadException` is arise because your work is too  much load on UI thread so just use or do that particular work under `AsyncTask`, so you never get this error :)

Comment: This isn't their question. They are complaining that there are thousands of these type of question.