# Automatically generated tag-specific FAQ

Tags: feature-request, tags, duplicate-questions, tag-wiki

**Proposal:** Automatically generate a list of tag-specific Frequently Asked Questions:

- Questions that are often the close-as-duplicate-of targets in that tag, possibly weighed by votes.
- Display similarly as "Recent Hot Answers" on the /tags/foo/info page. That is, display top 5 in the right pane with a "more" link.

Screenshot with obligatory hand-drawn red circle:

[image: Screenshot of /tags/android/info with Recent Hot Answers made even hotter with a red hand-drawn circle]

**Background:**

Many tag wikis have manually curated FAQs. After [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212969/how-to-ask-correctly-for-android-problems/212972) I started one for the [android](/questions/tagged/android) tag, starting with the three questions shown in the screenshot above. Even though I regularly put in my 40 close vote reviews in that tag and I am therefore quite familiar with the frequent duplicates, coming up with a list of frequent dupes is not an easy task. Computers are good at counting and could help there. So the idea is not to replace manually curated FAQs, just to provide additional computer-generated FAQ that could also help in manual wiki-based FAQ curation. And also to help close voters to pick a "canonical" duplicate for a frequently duplicated question.

**Related meta questions:**

[Auto-generation of a FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61752/auto-generation-of-a-faq)

- About the same idea but without explicitly being tag-specific.

[Per-tag FAQ for finding dupes - needed? Wanted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61308/per-tag-faq-for-finding-dupes-needed-wanted)

- Discussion but not a specific proposal for automatic generation of FAQs.